# why my newly created table is sorted based on the first column?

Tags: postgresql, sorting

I have created a new table using the following script (basically loading csv file's data into the table) - note, that my data in the csv file in NOT sorted based on any of the table columns:

```
CREATE TABLE dynamic_se_down_13patients_dynamicranking
(
SE_ID  character(80) NOT NULL,
downreg_agk_se_ranking float,
downreg_bvi_se_ranking float,
downreg_cbk_se_ranking float,
downreg_dj_se_ranking float,
downreg_dkj_se_ranking float,
downreg_flv_se_ranking float,
downreg_ghw_se_ranking float,
downreg_gvz_se_ranking float,
downreg_idy_se_ranking float,
downreg_prw_se_ranking float,
downreg_spn_se_ranking float,
downreg_zgr_se_ranking float,
downreg_znk_se_ranking float,
CONSTRAINT SE_ID_Key PRIMARY KEY (SE_ID)
);

COPY dynamic_se_down_13patients_dynamicranking FROM 'G:\CarrollLab\Teena\Enhancers\EnhancerAnalysis\12_PreferentiallyANDExclusiveSuperEnhancersData\FigsAndTangentSuperEnhancers\DynamicSuperEnhancersValues\OutputFromPostgres\dynamic_se_down_13patientsHM.csv' WITH (FORMAT 'csv', DELIMITER E',', NULL '',HEADER);
```

My table is being loaded just fine onto postgres, but then when i open it (view the data..) the table is opened as sorted. it is sorted based on its first column in this manner (only the first column data presented here):

```
chr3:81872627-81874608@NM_000158@GBE1                                           
chr3:81886043-81891012@NM_000158@GBE1                                           
chr3:82119808-82144698@NM_000158@GBE1                                           
chr3:98270559-98285850@NM_005290@GPR15                                          
chr4:101067675-101092752@NM_145244@DDIT4L                                       
chr4:101159314-101161672@NM_145244@DDIT4L                                       
chr4:101931434-101943063@NM_000944@PPP3CA                                       
chr4:102676016-102684334@NM_001127507@BANK1                                     
chr4:103390927-103396488@NM_001165412@NFKB1
```

I'm not sure why the table is being sorted(!?)
When i go to "sort/filter options" at the control bar of postgres, i see indeed that Data Sorting has my first column name: "se_id" and the sort order is set as Ascending.

If I choose this item and click 'Remove', and 'Ok' then my table is back to 'normal' and presented finally in its unsorted format. 
Is there a way to avoid the automatic sorting that postgres does??
I noticed that other tables of mine are being loaded 'normally' (=unsorted), but i can't figure why in this specific case my table is being sorted (I've tried creating the same table a few times, and in each time the same problem occurs). Thanks!

Comment: When you say you "open it" you mean using View Data functionality of pgAdmin? As far as I know this is default behavior in View data in pgAdmin. Perhaps the other tables appear unsorted because they have generated IDs and the IDs therefore match the order in which the rows were created unlike the import?

Comment: Rows in a relational database are not "sorted". The ***only*** (!) way to get a specific ordering of rows is to use `order by` in the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you should understand here is that the view you're seeing has nothing to do with how the DBMS is storing the data.  The fact that it *appears* to be sorted as you're viewing it is an artifact of the tool you're using to view the data.  The actual order of the data on the database server is completely orthogonal to what you're seeing.

If you were to connect to the database using some other tool perform a

```
SELECT * 
FROM dynamic_se_down_13patients_dynamicranking
```

... query then you might see the rows in the order in which they were inserted or in some arbitrary ordering (perhaps resulting from some indexing or hashing done by the DB server as they were inserted or as the tables were being maintain by something like a vacuum operation).

So this question is really about whatever tool you're using to view your PostgreSQL data.

As others have pointed out you should add an SQL `ORDER BY` clause to specify your desired ordering/sorting parameters.